# Paperclip - check for presence of given format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

In papercip's documentation I've found a way to see whether the image had been uploaded:

```
@my_model.my_image.present?
```

Is there a way to check if any particular dimension is present? As in:

```
@my_model.my_image(:thumb).present?
```

In order to verify if thumb is present.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a convenience method, but doing this should work:

```
File.exist?(@my_model.my_image.path(:thumb))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write `@my_model.my_image?`